# Can't get entries to appear in flask web application

Tags: python, forms, input, sqlite, flask

I am trying to create a basic web application that accepts text inputs on the "add queries" page and then displays them in the "search Queries" page. So far, I have successfully connected the database, and the website doesn't throw an error when I use it.

However, when I enter an input and click submit on the "Add Queries" page, the "Search Queries" page doesn't update or display any new inputs.

I think that there is something wrong in my code which isn't linking the inputs to the database.

**UPDATE:** Someone has mentioned that I don't call the methods "add_entry" and "show_entries" in my view subclass. However, shouldn't my main py file handle functions?

Here are some basic screenshots for the webapp that I am developing:

[image]

[image]

The following represents my py files:

This is my main py file (queries-Final2.py)

```
#functions
def show_entries():
    db = get_db()
    cur = db.execute('select title, columns, query, notes, tags from entries order by id desc')
    entries = [dict(title=row[0], columns=row[1],query=row[2],notes=row[3],tags=row[4]) for row in cur.fetchall()]
    return render_template('search-queries.html', entries=entries)

def add_entry():
    if not session.get('logged_in'):
    abort(401)
    db = get_db()
     db.execute('insert into entries (title, columns, query, notes, tags) values (?, ?)',
      [request.form['title'],
       request.form['columns'],
       request.form['query'],
       request.form['notes'],
       request.form['tags']
       ])
    db.commit()
     flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return redirect(url_for('add-queries'))


# Routes
   app.add_url_rule('/',
   view_func=Main.as_view('main'),
   methods=["GET"])

   app.add_url_rule('/login/',
   view_func=Login.as_view('login'),
   methods=["GET", "POST"])

   app.add_url_rule('/search-queries/',
   view_func=SearchQueries.as_view('search-queries'),
   methods=["GET", "POST"])

   app.add_url_rule('/add-queries/',
   view_func=AddQueries.as_view('add-queries'),
   methods=["GET", "POST"])

   app.add_url_rule('/edit-queries/',
   view_func=EditQueries.as_view('edit-queries'),
   methods=["GET", "POST"])
```

As well as the class files:

This is my "Search Queries" page view

```
class SearchQueries(flask.views.MethodView):
  @utils.login_required
  def get(self):
    return flask.render_template('search-queries.html')
```

This is my "Add Queries" page view

```
class AddQueries(flask.views.MethodView):
  @utils.login_required
  def get(self):
    return flask.render_template('add-queries.html')

  def post(self):
    return flask.render_template('search-queries.html')
```

These are my html files:

This is my "add queries" html page

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="pageHeader" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">Add a query</h1>
<h3 class="pageSubHeader">Sooo many queries to add</h3>
<form action="{{ url_for('add-queries') }}" method=post class=add-entry>
    <dl>
        <dt>Title:
        <dd><input type=text size=54 name=title>
        <dt>Columns: (Store ID, Date, transaction-total, etc... )
        <dd><textarea name=columns rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
        <br>
        <dt>Query: (The text of the query)
        <dd><textarea name=query rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
        <br>
        <dt>Notes: (Anything that the analyst should note)
        <dd><textarea name=notes rows=5 cols=40></textarea>
        <br>
        <dt>Tags: (traffic, conversion, etc... )
        <dd><input name=tags type=text size=54>
        <br>
        <dd><input type=submit value="Submit query">
    </dl>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

This is my "search queries" html page

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h1 class="pageHeader">Have fun searching for queries</h1>
    <h3 class="pageSubHeader">Search for a large query</h3>
    <ul class=entries>
      {% for entry in entries %}
         <li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.columns|safe }}
      {% else %}
          <li><em>Unbelievable.  No entries here so far</em>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

There may be something really obvious that I am missing so any help here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

- Lowly intern

**UPDATE:** my database uses SQLite3

and the schema.sql file is as follows:

```
drop table if exists entries;
create table entries (
  id integer primary key autoincrement,
  title string not null,
  columns string not null,
  query string not null,
  notes string not null,
  tags string not null
 );
```

**Question:** In the example that I was looking at, the developer used

```
 @app.route('/add/')
```

before declaring the function. What does this do?

Comment: I dont get the question. And really a lot of code in here.

Comment: agreed with alex, your question is not clear, not even sure what your intending to do.

Comment: I updated the question to make what I am asking more clear. Basically, I have no idea why the inputs are not showing up in the database.

Comment: `entries = [dict(title=row[0], text=row[1]) for row in cur.fetchall()]` but `<li><h2>{{ entry.title }}</h2>{{ entry.columns|safe }}`.  
Inconsistently named field `columns`/`text` is your first problem.

Comment: Second, you need to give us more clarity as to your question.  Fix the formatting; I can't tell where your functions end.  Also, you need to add the titles to every single document, because I can't tell which html file belongs to which Python function, etc.

Comment: I changed the entries line as you suggested. However, I still can't seem to get the database to read the input from the "add queries" page.

Comment: Also, what does your database/models look like?

Comment: Are those '#Routes' indented correctly?

Comment: Where in the code do you actually call add_entries, show_entries? They are not in the MethodView subclasses, afaict.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time that I have attempted to create a flask application so I might be making some noob mistakes here. Where should I add the functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, nowhere in your code do you actually *call* your `add_entries` and `show_entries` functions.

I'm not a fan of view classes, so I've never used them, however, would you not do something like this:

```
class AddQueries(flask.views.MethodView):
  @utils.login_required
  def get(self):
    return flask.render_template('add-queries.html')

  def post(self):
    db = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into entries (title, columns, query, notes, tags) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
    [request.form['title'],
     request.form['columns'],
     request.form['query'],
     request.form['notes'],
     request.form['tags']
    ])
    db.commit()
    flash('New entry was successfully posted')
    return flask.render_template('search-queries.html')
```

so basically, when you `POST` something to the `AddQueries` view, it *actually* inserts it into the database. Similarly, your `ShowQueries` class would need to *actually* run the code currently in your `show_entries()` function.

Comment: What implementation would you use if you are not using the view classes?

Comment: I'm not saying classes are a bad way to do it, I just don't like the separated routing and 'magic' methods like `get()` and whatever. My brain struggles to track it all!